# Jira Structure - showing issue link type in formula column

Tags: jira, jira-plugin

Using the [Jira Structure](https://almworks.com/structure/overview.html) plugin, I have generally this type of organization.

```
Issue1
  Issue2
    Issue3
      Issue4 (blocks Issue3)
  Issue5
```

This is done using the automatic generators.  Roughly, populate the list of all issue1s, the extending with relations with the last level being issues related that block their parents.  So in this case, Issue4 blocks Issue3.

What I desire, is an indicator on Issue1 that highlights it has a blocking issue in it's tree.  Then when I expand issue1, I see the indicator on Issue2, then Issue3 until we get to the blocking issue.  I suspect this can be done with a custom formula column, but I'm unable to find a way to make it work.

I figure I can use the wiki markup like explained [here](https://youtu.be/0iDLFcSeB8I?t=1363) to make the indicator, but how can I detect a parent has children that are blocked?  I feel like it should be something be like:

```
IF(anyChildrenLinkType()="Blocked by", ShowIndicator(), DoNothing())
```